# Select in ember not loading data - is there working example?

Tags: select, ember.js

I'm new to Ember JS and I am trying to figure out how to create Ember.Select which would allow to create new job for user.

This is part of the code from my form.handlebars:

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="job-user"
            contentBinding="users"
            optionLabelPath="content.name"
            optionValuePath="content.id"

            }}
```

I am inside JobsNewController:

```
JP.JobsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['users'],
    users: [],
    usersBinding: "controllers.users"

});
```

This is how my UsersController looks like:

```
JP.UsersController =  Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

It's working when I go to newJob screen from screen where I have UserController populated, but when I go directly to jobs/new it fails to populate select with data. How can I force Ember to load data for this select?

---

EDIT:
I had to setup routes correctly:

```
JP.JobsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend( JP.JobsFormable, {
    model: function() {
        return JP.Job.createRecord();
    },
    setupController:function(controller,model) {
        this._super(controller,model);
        controller.set('usersForSelect', JP.User.find());
    }
});
```

And I have also modified form:

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="job-user"
   contentBinding="usersForSelect"
   optionLabelPath="content.name"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
}}
```

Thanks @mavilein for hint

Comment: So, it basically works when you are navigating through the app the 'normal way'. Your problem is about entering the app via URL. So the problem is not about the code you are showing here. It is about the Routes and their implementations. Can you show your Router and Routes? I guess that there is a JobsRoute and JobsNewRoute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access the `JobsNewRoute` from the URL, the `UsersController` is not populated.  So binding `users` in `JobsNewController` to `UsersController` content would be useless since `UsersController` is empty and was not populated.

You can solve this in two ways, both are in the `JobsNewRoute`.

First way, update your `JobsNewRoute` to fill the `UsersController`:

```
JP.JobsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('content', JP.User.find());
  }
});
```

Another way would be to remove the binding between `JobsNewController.users` and `UsersController`, and simply fill `JobsNewController.users` in the `JobsNewRoute`:

```
JP.JobsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  users: []
});


JP.JobsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('users', JP.User.find());
  }
});
```